# Android Java, a onliner ListView with a single highlighted selection

Tags: android, listview

I have work on Android for a few years now, yet I still can not find a simple one liner that set up a simple list view with a single highlighted selection, and it need to meet the following criteria :

1. Work with any target API above 16
2. Work with any theme the activity is using. e.g if you use dark theme, the selection is light and other item is dark, in light theme, the selection is dark and item is light.
3. The data is array of string or array of object with toString () override

A example use in java will be like :

```
   String tutorials[]
            = { "Algorithms", "Data Structures",
            "Languages", "Interview Corner",
            "GATE", "ISRO CS",
            "UGC NET CS", "CS Subjects",
            "Web Technologies" };


   ListView l = findViewById(R.id.list);

   l.SetData ( tutorials ) ;
```

I am sure this is VERY VERY COMMON usage, but still I can  not find a solution.

Comment: You're not going to find a 1 liner to do what you want.  First off, ListView has been deprecated in favor of RecyclerView for a decade.  Secondly, both ListView and RecyclerView are meant to be more generic than that.  They don't just take data you need to map the data to your UI.  The reason for that is that UIs really aren't that generic.  A component that just fits text to a view is never going to magically guess the background color you want, the padding you want, the text size you want, etc.  So you have to build the UI and the binder for that information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but a "Generic" UI is precisely what I want.  I don't care about the color, the padding, the text size (it should be fit_content, and cutoff or wrap around). I think it probably all comes down to to have a system color like android.color.List_Selection_Background, but I can not find such a system color,

Comment: That's fine if its what you want.  But it doesn't exist as a one liner.  You can follow a very simple RecyclerView tutorial and write a class to do that for you, but it isn't built in.